# Convert Collection to Capped with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, capped-collections

I would like to convert a mongo collection to capped using `gopkg.in/mgo.v2`.

I am able to create a capped collection from scratch - as follows:

```
# Create a Capped Collection
sess.DB("").C("my_collection").Create(&mgo.CollectionInfo{Capped: true, MaxBytes: tenMB, MaxDocs: 10})
```

I can't work out how to get the stats for an existing collection or how to run `convertToCapped` command.

Step 1 - Get Collection Stats:

```
# Mongo
db.getCollection('my_collection').stats();

# mgo // I need to find out how to do this.
```

Step 2 - Convert to Capped

```
# Mongo
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "my_collection", size: 1000000});

# mgo // I need to find out how to do this.
if err := sess.DB("").Run(bson.D{{"convertToCapped", "my_collection"}, {"size", "1000"}}, nil); err != nil {
        println(err.Error()) // invalid command spec
        os.Exit(1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Get Collection Stats

This is not part of the `mgo` package, but it is available as a runnable MongoDB command: [`collStats`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#dbcmd.collStats).

Running `collStats` with `mgo`:

```
var doc bson.M
err := mgr.sess.DB("").Run(bson.D{
    {Name: "collStats", Value: "my_collection"},
}, &doc)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    return
}

fmt.Println("Result:", doc)
fmt.Println("Capped:", doc["capped"])
// Acquire capped info as a bool value:
capped, ok := doc["capped"].(bool)
if ok {
    fmt.Println("Capped bool value:", capped)
}
```

Example output (*veeeeeeery* long so chunked):

```
Result: map[ok:1 size:36 storageSize:4096 totalIndexSize:4096  ...chunked...]
Capped: true
Capped bool value: true
```

### 2. Converting to Capped

The simple problem with your attempt is that the value of the `"size"` parameter must be a number and not a `string`. Quoting from the [`convertToCapped`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/convertToCapped/#dbcmd.convertToCapped) doc:

> The command has the following syntax:
>
> ```
>   { convertToCapped: <collection>, size: <capped size> }
> ```
>
> `convertToCapped` takes an existing collection (`<collection>`) and transforms it into a capped collection with a maximum size in bytes, specified by the `size` argument (`<capped size>`).

Correct version:

```
var doc bson.M
err := mgr.sess.DB("").Run(bson.D{
    {Name: "convertToCapped", Value: "my_collection"},
    {Name: "size", Value: 1<<20}, // 1 MB
}, &doc)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    return
}

fmt.Println("Result:", doc)
```

Example output:

```
Result: map[ok:1]
```